# Ok.ru integration with ios - Redirect URI Error

Tags: android, ios

I am trying to integrate the ok.ru sdk for an iOS game following [these instructions](http://apiok.ru/wiki/display/api/iOS+application).
The app is created on the website following instructions mentioned [here](http://apiok.ru/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42476486). But when I try to post something, I get the error message

> "Indicated redirect_uri is not registered in App Settings.
>   redirect_uri:ok1139715840://authorize"

The problem is that the redirect uri contains the app id that is obtained only after app creation. 
According to [this link](http://apiok.ru/wiki/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=84836377), the redirect uri needs to be mentioned when creating the app. I cant even go back and edit the app settings as when I click on the app, it says "Page not found". 
Has anyone successfully integrated this sdk?

Can some instructions be provided (in english) on how to do this successfully and get rid of the current error??
The same error will arise with the android sdk as that also a redirect uri as shown in the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out:
You have to scroll to the bottom of the page and then you will find an App Settings button. Click on it, enter your application secret and then you will be able to edit the app settings.

Answer (score 1):

Go to odnoklassniki API page, and chan your application url to "http://localhost" while you developing. 
Once it's in production then change with your site.

API page : http://apiok.ru

Comment: Can you please give the link to the API page?I cant seem to find it.Thanks.

Comment: TheDevilsFire, I updated my answer above. Please check and let me know if you fix your problem.

Comment: But I can't find the application settings. The instructions on this page mention how to create a new app. Do I have to create a new app and then add local host? Is there no way to edit the settings of the existing app?

Comment: it's like Facebook, naturally you need to create account + app .etc.

Comment: I have already created an account and an app. I think I wat not clear - The problem is that unless u create the app, u won't get the app ID, which u need for the redirect URI, which can be added only when creating the app. Once the app is created, there is no way to go back and change the app settings as it says "Page not found". In this scenario I cannot add the redirect URI once the app has already been created.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the app settings in Odnoklassniki and add ok1139715840://authorize to accepted redirect_uri list